# How to create session of object value in asp.net core version 2.2.0?

Tags: session, asp.net-core, session-state

In Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session version 2.2.0 how to create session of object value.
I have tried to read various article, but when I am trying to apply same it gives me error, because there is no overload as 'SetString'.

```
public static class SessionHelper
    {
        public static void SetObjectAsJson<T>(this ISession session, string key, object value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);

            return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Asp.Net Core apart from setting and getting session string, you also have add the SessionMiddleware to the pipeline, do this `app.UseSession()` before the `app.UseMvc()` in the Configure method in your startup.cs file. After that in your ConfigureServices method, add the following service.

```
services.AddSession(options =>
  {
      //Replace {mins} with the time you want, usually around 20-30.
      options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes({mins});               
  });
```

and then you can continue with the SessionHelper class.
Also the name of your class is wrong, it should be called SessionExtensions and not SessionHelper, maybe that's why your extension doesn't get registered with HttpContext.Session.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I create  'Session Extensions ' class in business layer or it need's to be web solution.Thanks for helping me I was actually using same code which you have mentioned above only problem was that I have created class with wrong name and at wrong place.

Comment: Yes, you can have extension methods written separately. All you have to do is to add the directive for that method in your controller or view, wherever you want to be get or set the session object. If you've never written an extension method before this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) can help you. Happy coding!

Comment: I am not able fetch session values on different controller.